# Adding a div element in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am having a helper function as

```
 def link_to_user(text, user, options = {})
options[:class] = options.has_key?(:class) ? "#{options[:class]} user-link" : ""
content_tag :span, :class => :vcard do
  link_to(text, user, options) +
  content_tag(:span, :style => "display: none;", :class => "userbox") do
    content_tag(:span, :class => "fn") do
      content_tag(:span, :class => "given-name") do user.firstname
       end +
      content_tag(:span, :class => "family-name") do #user.lastname 
       end
    end 
  end
end
```

end

now i am trying to add a div element as a sibling to vcard span. i tried but i am getting errors as  syntax error, unexpected '+', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)

please give suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
@content = content_tag :span, :class => :vcard do
    link_to(text, user, options) +
    content_tag(:span, :style => "display: none;", :class => "userbox") do
      content_tag(:span, :class => "fn") do
        content_tag(:span, :class => "given-name") do user.firstname
        end +
        content_tag(:span, :class => "family-name") do #user.lastname 
        end
      end 
    end
  end
@content << content_tag(:div, "etc")
```

Comment: @content << content_tag(:div, , :style => "display: none;", :class => "userdetail")
if i gave like above the div is not hiddden

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the syntax for passing an argument to a block is

```
method_call do |arg|
```

you are missing the pipes (`|`)

secondly, you are missing an `end`